# Number of interrupts last second (Bash)

Tags: bash, interrupt

I'm programming in Bash and I'm trying to find out how many interrupts that happend the last second.

I've searched and tried to find how many interrupts total, so I could use sleep 1 and calculate the difference, but with no success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Linux or BSD or OSX or which OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is [similar to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948362/cpu-time-used-last-second/21949149). Once again, `vmstat(8)` will be our friend.

Example output:

```
$ vmstat 1 2
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0    752 135436  31276 392252    0    0     2     1   40  101  0  0 99  0
 0  0    752 138404  31396 392816    0    0     0     0   68  188  1  1 98  0
```

The first line is the average since reboot, the second line is a sampling of the last second.

From the manpage:

```
   System
       in: The number of interrupts per second, including the clock.
       cs: The number of context switches per second.
```

We can use `awk(1)` to parse the output:

```
ints=$(vmstat 1 2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $11}')
```

This should work on Linux, FreeBSD, and probably MacOSX.

Answer (score 0):

Just a food for thought you can do something like this

watch "cat /proc/interrupts |awk '{print \$1,\$2}'"

By passing -n to watch command you dont need sleep option and you can have decide when you get an output

-n, --interval

Comment: The [`cat` is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and getting rid of it could simplify the command considerably in this case.